# if else sql statement (select statement with param and without param)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

```
CASE 
   WHEN @vessel_certificate_id IS NULL 
      THEN SELECT 
               id, name as file_name,
               SUM(DATALENGTH(data)) / 1048576.0  AS file_size,
               dbo.fn_format_datetime(created_on) as file_date  
           FROM
               vessel_cert_attachment 
           GROUP BY 
               id, name, type, created_by, created_on 
      ELSE 
          SELECT
              id, name as file_name, 
              SUM(DATALENGTH(data)) / 1048576.0  AS file_size ,
              dbo.fn_format_datetime(created_on) as file_date  
          FROM 
              vessel_cert_attachment 
          WHERE 
              vessel_certificate_id = @vessel_certificate_id 
          GROUP BY 
              id, name, type, created_by, created_on
```

Based on the SQL above if the param is not null, I want it to execute select statement without param and if there is param passing I want it to execute the select statement with where condition.

Is it possible to execute it like that?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that **returns ONE, single, atomic value** - you cannot use `CASE` do conditionally execute one code block or another - for that, you need to `IF .... ELSE ....`

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` condition in `Where` clause

```
SELECT id,
       NAME                               AS file_name,
       Sum(Datalength(data)) / 1048576.0  AS file_size,
       dbo.Fn_format_datetime(created_on) AS file_date
FROM   vessel_cert_attachment
WHERE  ( vessel_certificate_id = @vessel_certificate_id
          OR @vessel_certificate_id IS NULL )
GROUP  BY id,
          NAME,
          type,
          created_by,
          created_on
```

Comment: Plus read the [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) article by Erland Sommarskog to understand why you'd better add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to this kind of query.